# Template partials within a template partial (is that OK?)

Tags: template-partials

I have a template partial within another template partial. And that seems to work.

Is this a coincidence or correctly so?

If it is correct, where to stop with such a nesting? A partial that has a partial in a partial?

Thanks for some clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The amount of nesting possible is probably limited by your php environment.  I created a recursive template partial called `tp_recurse` containing this code:

```
X {tp_recurse}
```

If I include it in a template the host for the EE instance appears to crash, but takes a while to do so: which suggests that the recursion is executing - which in turn suggests there is scope to nest template partials for quite a few levels I would expect.

HTH